# Logstash - parse array of jsons in json event

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

i would like to parse some fields from json logs from AWS WAF. On input logstash use:

```
s3 {
    bucket => "XXXX"
    access_key_id     => "XXXX"
    secret_access_key => "XXXX"
    prefix            => "waf/"
    region       => "XXX"
    sincedb_path => "/tmp/s3.sincedb"
    add_field    => [ "lso_name", "NULL", "lsi_type", "s3", "lsi_name", "waf" ]
    codec        => "json"
}
```

I get messages like:

```
{
    "httpSourceName"=>"CF",
    "httpRequest"=> {
        "clientIp"=>"XX.XX.XX.XX",
        "httpMethod"=>"GET",
        "requestId"=>"XXXX",
        "uri"=>"XXX", 
        "headers"=>
            [
                {"name"=>"Host", "value"=>"test.exmaple.com"},
                {"name"=>"user-agent", "value"=>"Mozilla/5.0"},
                {"name"=>"accept", "value"=>"*/*"}
            ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to parse that header in logstash filter, but cant do it.

Output in kibana should be like:

```
"httpRequest.headers.Host" => "test.example.com"
"httpRequest.headers.user-agent" => "Mozilla/5.0"
```

I tryed json filter even kv, but with no success.

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: What happens if there are two headers with same name?

Comment: I am not sure, that can even happend.

Comment: Rare case. But it is possible to receive headers with same name in http. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502132/http-header-key-can-be-repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way will be to use a ruby code. Something like below. I have not tested it. But basically it is creating new events from headers array. It may have issue if there are more than one event with same name. It might overwrite with last one.

```
 ruby {
      init => "
        def process_headers obj, event
          if obj.is_a? Array
            obj.each {|a|
              event.set("[httpRequest][headers]["+a['name']+"]")=a['value']
            }
          end
        end
      "
      code => "
        process_headers(event.get["httpRequest][headers]",event)
        "
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes it could be done with ruby like that, thank you. I thought that can be done with some build-in plugin.